# Exporting Sqlite table data to csv file programatically - xcode iOS 5 (for an ipad app)

Tags: ios, csv, sqlite, export

I am developing a simple app. I am using sqlite to save data into a table (locally, in app documents folder). I want to problematically export this table data in a csv file and email it to a person. [Export SQLite data to Excel in iOS programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132900/export-sqlite-data-to-excel-in-ios-programmatically) - I tried this, but its not working... Can anybody give an example application to download? Or the code?

Currently, I am using these commands in command line to convert a db table to csv - .mode, .output out.csv, select * from table;

Please help

Comment: When you say its not working, what is not working? What happens, errors, logs?

Comment: // TODO: mutex lock?
    [sqliteDb exportCsv: csvPath];

-This is the place I dont understand... So I used the documentpath instead... do you think the code is a working code? Do you have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here what i have done to generate csv for tabular data.
Here i have done it for simple testing. but what you need to do is to generate 2d array in such manner to produce NSArray like one i have done in this sample.

Here first component in NSArray is one row for table , second component is for second row of table and likewise...

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"NAME,NUMBER",@"\nbhargavi1,12345",@"\nHiral,23456",@"\nHarish,34567", nil];    

NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test.csv"];
NSString *filePathLib = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];

[[array componentsJoinedByString:@","] writeToFile:filePathLib atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

please implement this. May be this could help you out.

i have implement this in my project and it works for me very nicely

Comment: If phone number is 10 digit then it gives different format. Also I want to have new line in a column. It will be like I have two phone numbers, then In phone column it will be on two lines but in same row.

Comment: @Durgaprasad I have not tried new line in same column, if you find solution for same then post here so that others can review same.