# Swift - Export SQLite database to excel/text?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

In my application I am saving some data using SQLite, where I do have a few columns and rows. Is there any solution to export this to either excel file or text file?

FYI: The reason I want this is because I want to connect it to Mail app and send the file as an attachment in email.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132900/export-sqlite-data-to-excel-in-ios-programmatically